# Move to next record using odbc_connect with Access database

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

Is this even possible?

I did find

```
$user='';
$password='';
$mdbFilename="myDatabase.accdb";

$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM [tblNameHere]";
$rs=odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

$myResults=odbc_result($rs,"fieldNameHere");

echo 'First entry: ' . $myResults;

//Move to next record here
$myResults=odbc_result($rs,"fieldNameHere");
echo 'Second entry: ' . $myResults;

odbc_close($connection);
```

This just puts the first record twice, I can return any field value of the first record, but I cannot find get it to change to the next record, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the records, use `odbc_fetch_row`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM [tblNameHere]";
$rs=odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
   $myResults =odbc_result($rs,"fieldNameHere");
   echo "Entry: " . $myResults;
}

odbc_close($connection);
```

---

> [**odbc_fetch_row**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-row.php)
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5) odbc_fetch_row — Fetch a row
>
> **Description**
>
> `bool odbc_fetch_row ( resource $result_id [, int $row_number ] )`
>   Fetches a row of the data that was returned by `odbc_do()` or
>   `odbc_exec()`. After `odbc_fetch_row()` is called, the fields of that row
>   can be accessed with `odbc_result()`.

---

"Manually"

```
$rs=odbc_exec($connection,$sql);

$myResults=odbc_result($rs,"fieldNameHere");
echo 'First entry: ' . $myResults;

//Move to next record here
odbc_fetch_row($rs); //<----MoveNext() manually

$myResults=odbc_result($rs,"fieldNameHere");
echo 'Second entry: ' . $myResults;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a loop at all?  I have been able to do it with COM using $rs->fields['fieldNameHere'] and $rs->MoveNext() to move to the next record

Comment: @NickySunblade why you dont want the loop? you have a resultset how can you iterate without loop?

Comment: oh ok so this is what they call it in odbc `odbc_fetch_row($rs)` to move the cursor to next row in the resultset just like in `COM C++`

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly, thank you!  (NOTE: You must have the correct ODBC driver installed, although it may seem obvious, I had the wrong version of a driver installed.)

Comment: @NickySunblade great! and sorry I couldnt understand what you meant by manually at first.